# numpy.linalg.eigvals shows different values for the transpose of a matrix - is this due to overflow?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I'm getting different answers coming from `np.linalg.eigvals` depending on whether I use the transpose of a matrix.

To replicate:

```
mat = np.array([[ -7.00616288e-08,  -2.79704289e-09 ,  1.67598654e-10],
 [ -3.23676574e+07,  -1.58978291e+15,   0.00000000e+00],
 [  0.00000000e+00  , 1.80156232e-02 , -2.32851854e+07]])

print(np.linalg.eigvals(mat))
print(np.linalg.eigvals(mat.transpose()))
```

I get:

```
[ -7.00616288e-08  -1.58978291e+15  -2.32851854e+07]
[ -1.58978291e+15   2.50000000e-01  -2.32851854e+07]
```

Note that these values are different. Since the eigenvalues of  a matrix and its transpose are identical, I assume that these issues are due to overflow. Is there some maximum value I should limit to, to make sure that this is always consistent?

Comment: These values aren't that different. Two values match exactly, the smallest is the same within 1e-20 relative to the larger ones. That's actually good precision. Could be accounted for by the different order.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The important thing for me is that I'm looking for positive eigenvalues (instabilities of a dynamical system) and this basically gives me a different stability depending on whether I do the transpose...

Comment: I'm suggesting that you should filter out zeros before checking. Something 10^-20 times the max eigenvalue is clearly zero, regardless of sign, and shouldn't affect your count.

Comment: The differences are not due to overflow. They are due to rounding errors, caused by limited precision. Given such large variations in the magnitudes of elements in the input array, are you even sure they are accurate enough for eigenvalues to be computed accurately even if exact mathematics were used for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not due to an overflow. Overflow is easy to detect, and it generates a warning. The issue is the limit of double precision: significant digits can be lost when numbers of very different magnitudes are added, and then subtracted. For example, `(1e20 + 1) - 1e20 == 0`.

The second result, with 2 negative eigenvalues, is incorrect, because the determinant of your matrix is clearly negative: the product of main-diagonal entries is of magnitude 1e15 and dominates all other terms in the determinant by a large margin. So the sign of the determinant is the sign of this product, which is negative.

The issue is that `mat.T` has all tiny entries in the first column, much smaller than those in other columns. When looking for a pivot, an algorithm may scan that column and settle for what is found there. This is not necessarily how `.eigvals` works, but same principle -- numerical linear algebra algorithms tend to proceed from the upper left corner, and so it's best to avoid small entries there. Here's one way to:

```
mat1 = np.roll(mat, 1, axis=[0, 1])
print(np.linalg.eigvals(mat1))
print(np.linalg.eigvals(mat1.T))
```

prints

```
[-7.00616288e-08 -2.32851854e+07 -1.58978291e+15]
[-2.32851854e+07 -1.58978291e+15 -7.00616288e-08]
```

which are consistent. Rolling *both*  axes means conjugating `mat` by a permutation matrix, which does not change the eigenvalues. The rolled matrix is

```
[[-2.32851854e+07  0.00000000e+00  1.80156232e-02]
 [ 1.67598654e-10 -7.00616288e-08 -2.79704289e-09]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -3.23676574e+07 -1.58978291e+15]]
```

which gives NumPy a nice large number to start with.

Ideally it would do something like that itself, but no (practical) algorithm is ideal for every situation.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented constraints on the systems that I'm looking at so these orders of magnitude are not so different and the code is much better behaved.